# Bullet becomes bullet hole

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my project, I have gun. My bullet uses rigidbody and spawns at the barrel of the gun when I fire. My bullet bounces through walls , sometimes it goes through walls.

Well I know, in physics raycast it's very simple:

```
public GameObject par;
public int damage;

void Update()
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2, Screen.height / 2, 0));

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100))
        {
            GameObject particleClone = Instantiate(par, hit.point, Quaternion.LookRotation(hit.normal)) as GameObject;
            Destroy(particleClone, 2);
            hit.transform.SendMessage("ApplyDamage", damage, SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I do this in rigidbody?
Bullet becomes a particle system or a bullet hole image.

Should I use `OnCollisionEnter()` or `OnTriggerEnter()`?

How do I make it a bullethole image or a particle system?

Answer (score 2):

Both OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter could be used; however, have a look at this explanation on the differences: [**What is the difference between OnCollisionEnter and OnTriggerEnter?**](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/790724/what-is-the-difference-between-oncollisionenter-an.html)

Answer (score 1):

I found this JavaScript in: [RAYCAST, BULLET HOLES, AND RANDOM ARRAYS](http://xenosmashgames.com/raycast-bullet-holes-and-random-arrays/)

You take this and add to the Launcher of your weapon:

---

```
var bulletTex : GameObject[]; // creates an array to use random textures of bullet holes

function Update ()
{

   var fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward); //casts our raycast in the forward direction
   var hit : RaycastHit;
   Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, fwd * 10, Color.green); //drays our raycast and gives it a green color and a length of 10 meters

   if(Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, hit, 10))
   { //when we left click and our raycast hits something
         Instantiate(bulletTex[Random.Range(0,3)], hit.point, Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, hit.normal)); //then we'll instantiate a random bullet hole texture from our array and apply it where we click and adjust
   // the position and rotation of textures to match the object being hit
   }
}
```

Comment: my name says it all,can you translate it to c#?  c;